# Logstash Web Interface is it still available?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Is the web interface for Logstash still available or this has been replaced with Kibana?
I am using logstash-1.5.3.

Comment: Now, you can directly access the logs in Kibana UI or Elasticsearch UI(using plugins) loaded using logstash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, since [version 1.5 onwards](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/pull/2661), the Logstash Web UI has been completely removed and replaced with Kibana.